# Views Custom Condition Error

Tags: views

I got the error

> Fatal error: Class 'RulesEventSet' not found.

I got this error on installing the views_custom_conditions module module.

Please let me know the cause of this error as I Googled but didn't find the solution.

Comment: What module did you install when you got the error?

Comment: views_custom_conditions module

Comment: Try flushing your cache

Comment: In addition to Googling the error, always search the issue queue of the module you installed.  Make sure to search all issues, not just open issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [patch](http://drupal.org/node/1541888) that should fix your problem. Comment #10